# How to change background image after specific interval

Tags: php, wordpress, image, background, intervals

On a Wordpress website I want to change background image automatically after every ten minutes. So, this script should do that exactly:

`random_img.php`:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$result = array_merge(glob("../../uploads/*x1500.jpg"), glob("../../uploads/*1500x*.jpg"));
$seed = floor(time()/600); 
srand($seed); 
$random_image = $result[rand(0, length($result)-1)];
header('Location:'.$random_image.'');
```

I have two questions:

a) Is the code correct this way? I tried to enter it into the child's `functions.php` and it gave me some error about the array_merge thing, but I cannot see anything wrong there.

b) I need your help about how and where to call the function (meaning: placing the picture into the website). Is it something like

```
background: url(random_img.php) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

into the CSS file or does the call have to go into the head of `header.php` and how is it stated correctly?

I think, I tried both, already, and it did not work out.

Comment: I think, You Need `JavaScript` or `JQuery` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to output the image directly from the script here's what to do:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$result = array_merge(glob("../../uploads/*x1500.jpg"), glob("../../uploads/*1500x*.jpg"));
$seed = floor(time()/600); 
srand($seed); 
$random_image = $result[rand(0, length($result)-1)];
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($random_image));
readfile($random_image);
```

The CSS should remain the same.
Access the random image file directly to test if it works.

Comment: Do you mean to enter this line into index.php, header.php, footer.php (of Wordpress) or into the random_img.php itself?

Comment: Thank you, Lansen, I have simplified my code (see above) and added your line, but it does still not show any background image. :( The random_img.php and the css file lie in root/wp-content/themes/is-child/ and the path to uploads is root/wp-content/uploads. So, everything should be correct there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered / can you use javascript for this?

If so you could do something like (in jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $("body").css("background","new-background");
    },10000);
});
```

Edit: thought it was 10 seconds, not 10 minutes. In any case, just change the `10000` to `600000` for 10 minutes

If you want to do it just in PHP then you have to realise that without javascript, the code will only run when the page is loaded. So I would suggest setting a session with the timestamp that the background was last changed, and every time the page is loaded, check if the last timestamp was over 10 minutes ago and bring in a new background.

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
session_start();

$pic     = array( "../is/images/*x1500.jpg",
                  "../is/images/*1500x*.jpg" );
$pic_num = count($pic);

if( isset($_SESSION["bg_change"]) && ($_SESSION["bg_change"]-600)>time()  )
{
    # They have already visited and it has been 10 minutes since last background change
    # Update the BG image
    $_SESSION["bg_img"]    = $pic[ mt_rand(1,$pic_num)-1 ];
    $_SESSION["bg_change"] = time();
}
else
{
    # They have either not visited, or its not time to change
    # Give them the last set background or the default
    $_SESSION["bg_img"] = ( isset($_SESSION["bg_img"]) ? $_SESSION["bg_img"] : "../path/to/default/background" );
}
```

Then, later on in that document, assuming this comes before your HTML & CSS, you need to echo `$_SESSION["bg_img"]` in place of the background style rule.

```
...
<style type="text/css">

body
{
    background: <?= $_SESSION["bg_img"] ?>;
} 

</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, I would rather like to avoid Javascript.

Comment: I copied your code to the functions.php and changed the three paths accordingly, but it did not work (studio-scs.de). :\ That is the paths I used: "wp-content/uploads/*x1500.jpg", "wp-content/uploads/*1500x*.jpg" and "wp-content/uploads/".

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you exactly use my code. Read through it until you know what it does and why and then implement your own interpretation of the logic used

Comment: Man, if I had been able to work something out, I would not have asked here. ;) I really hate coding and I was lucky to get that bit of code above (mine in the question) correct. Or at least, I thought so.

Comment: I think it's because you're using an asterisk `*` in your file names. Why is that?

Comment: The asterisk is because there are a lot of pictures in the directory, BUT I need only those with ending ...x1500.jpg or ...1500x....jpg in the array.

Comment: You cant implement that logic here as the code I've given you treats each element in `$pic` as an individual file path